# Why does React not recognize a function passed down to another component?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-props

I have a parent component in which I am creating this function that gets passed down to another component:

```
export default withRouter(({ history }) => {
    const selectedRouteStyle = currentPath => {
        if (history.location.pathname === currentPath) {
            return {
                color: '#565958',
                fontWeight: '700',
                borderBottom: '2px solid #4292ff',
            }
        } else {
            return {
                color: '#989e9c',
            }   
        }
    };

    return (
        <Child 
            selectedRouteStyle={selectedRouteStyle}
        />
    );
});
```

In the Child component I reference selectedRouteStyle like this:

```
<Link 
    to="/profile/chronology" 
    className="App_profile_navigation_link"
    style={selectedRouteStyle('/profile/chronology')}
>
    Chronology 
</Link>
```

And from what I know it sjould work fine, but insted I get this error:

```
TypeError: selectedRouteStyle is not a function
```

How can I make react recognise this function?

Comment: `this.props.selectedRouteStyle`?

Comment: Can you show us the full code of the `<Child />` component? I'm thinking maybe it is related how you are dealing with the `props`. Like wrongly destructured in function component case.

Comment: This is how I am destructuring the props in the Child: 
export default ({ selectedRouteStyle }) => {}

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Class Component you should use `this.props.selectedRouteStyle('/profile/chronology')` and if you're using function Component you need to use `props.selectedRouteStyle('/profile/chronology')`